Delete Azure empty cloud only groups
I just want to know the simple powershell command to extract the list all azure cloud only groups which is empty,
The group's source should be cloud not WindowsAD server
Just try to extract
Get-AzureADGroupMember -all .count

Use Where-Object to remove the null items.

To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.

To list the cloud only groups which are empty use below powershell script:
$cloudGroups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true | Where-Object { $_.DirSyncEnabled -eq $null -and (Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).Count -lt 1 }

# Output the names of cloud-only groups
if ($cloudGroups.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host " Deleted Empty Cloud-only groups:"
    $cloudGroups | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.DisplayName }
} else {
    Write-Host "No cloud-only groups found."
}

Output:


To Delete the cloud-only groups which are empty:
$cloudGroups = Remove-AzureADGroup -All $true | Where-Object { $_.DirSyncEnabled -eq $null -and (Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).Count -lt 1 }

# Output the names of cloud-only groups
if ($cloudGroups.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host " Deleted Empty Cloud-only groups:"
    $cloudGroups | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.DisplayName }
} else {
    Write-Host "No cloud-only groups found."
}

